# How can I remove characters from filenames with awk or sed?

Tags: sed, awk

I have more than 1000 files that look like this.

```
kkk1a2o_A.txt
kkk1a73_A.txt
kkk2chj_A.txt
```

I would like to change the name of each file as follows

```
1a2o.txt
1a73.txt
2chj.txt
```

How can I do this with awk or sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `sed` or `awk`, just `bash` parameter expansion:

```
for f in *.txt
do
    dest=${f#kkk}
    dest=${dest%_A.txt}.txt
    mv "$f" "$dest"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` and `awk` operate on the content of a file, not on its name. You can just use `mv` in a loop:

```
for file in kkk*.txt ; do
    new=${file#kkk}
    mv "${file}" "${new%_A.txt}.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 printf "%s\n" * | sed 'h;s/kkk\([^_]*\)_A/\1/;H;g;s/^\(.*\)\n/mv -v \1 /e'
```